# docker login on jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have this:

```
docker login -u AWS --password-stdin https://aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

how can we run docker login (or the equivalent) on a Jenkins server?

I was able to get around this problem by using:

```
eval "$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ${region} --profile ${profile})"
```

but then I get this error after I try to run `docker push`:

> no basic auth credentials

Comment: Would recommend the AWS Credentials plugin combined with the Docker Pipeline plugin. Then you can `withCredentials([...]) { docker.withServer(...) }` and it would be really straightforward and functional. You may be able to do this with the regular Credentials plugin though; I am not sure from the info provided as to what your setup is for ECR.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks will give that a shot, if you want to add an answer, that might help will try it out today

Comment: I had a dumb moment and really I meant `docker.withRegistry`. I forgot the specific method and checked the wrong documentation.

Answer (score 10):

As @matt-schuchard mentioned, you can use the [Docker Pipeline Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker). In my case, I used `docker.withRegistry([...])`.

A complete example:

```
node {
    def app

    stage('Clone repository') {
        /* Clone your repo */

    }

    stage('Build image') {
        /* Build your image */

        app = docker.build("<image name>")
    }

    stage('Push image') {
        /* Push image using withRegistry. */
        docker.withRegistry('<your docker registry>', 'docker-private-credentials') {
            app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
            app.push("latest")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ecr:us-east-1, using ecr as a prefix worked in my case. I wasted so much time around debugging this. I wish they update the documentation on the plugin itself. It was clearly mentioned in the https://blog.mikesir87.io/2016/04/pushing-to-ecr-using-jenkins-pipeline-plugin/ but I missed it.